# Keypress Parent not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to prevent enter from being pressed and then fake click a button in jquery but I can't seem to fetch the parent of the key press. It is working to prevent the key press though. The alert is giving me '#undefined' when it should be '#(number)'

```
    $('.noEnterSubmit').keypress(
    function(e) {
        if ( e.which == 13 ) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('#'+$(this).parent().attr('id'));
        }
});
```

Below is the HTML button

```
<input type="text" id="242Quantity" button="242" class="noEnterSubmit" STYLE="font-size:10pt;text-align:right;font-weight: normal;" autocomplete="off" name="QUANTITY" size="1">
```

Comment: Are you sure you're looking for parent? Works here http://jsfiddle.net/LcB6U/

Comment: I bet bubbling/capturing kicks in. You bind keypress event to the wrong element.

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/LcB6U/1/ who is the parent of the button - can u add it to the HTML? Does it have an ID?

Comment: Ah nevermind I fixed it. I didnt want the parent I wanted the data-id (custom set) of the parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does work .   try this jsfiddle .   Enter on the input box

```
<div id="rSubmit">
  <input class="noEnterSubmit"></input>
</div>


http://jsfiddle.net/jspatel/5R6tQ/
```

Hope this helps